# Algebra question/geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

solving the system 3x + 2y = 21, (7 - x)² + y² = 2².
what does this mean ?

How to get the answer  (7−4/√13,6/√13)

Comment: The solution $(x,y)$ representing the intersection of the circle $(7-x)^2+y^2=2^2$ and line $3x+2y=22$ .

Comment: I was getting $(7-\frac{4}{\sqrt{13}},\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}})$.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It means to find the numerical values for x and y that make both equations true at the same time.  There are many ways to do so.  For example, in the first equation you might isolate for $x$, then substitute the expression you get for $x$ into the second equation.  This will give you a number for $y$, which when substituted into either of the original equations will yield a number for $x$.

Geometrically, the two equations describe curves in 2D space.  The points where they are both true is where the two curves intersect.  These intersection points are the points $(x,y)$ you will find by the above procedure - the numbers where the equations are both true.

Comment: what if the radius was 1?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have a linear graph 3x+2y=21 and a circle, with origin at (7,0) and a radius of 2. To solve this system, you need to find the intersection point of these 2 graphs.

Edit:
My algebraic solution:

$3x+2y=21\\
2y=21-3x\\
y=\frac{21-3x}{2}\\
(7-x)^2+\frac{9}{4} \cdot (7-x)^2=4\\
\frac{13}{4} \cdot (7-x)^2=4\\
(7-x)^2=\frac{16}{13}\\
x-7=\pm \frac{4}{\sqrt{13}}\\
x=7 \pm \frac{4}{\sqrt{13}}$

Comment: So if I want to find point H on my attached Image what information do I need?

Comment: My algebra is definitely stronger than my geometry so let me present an algebraic solution

Comment: Ok thanks so much

Comment: I just added it. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I plot this on a graph ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IdwJUjB.png

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psaea.png  So where exactly is H positioned at? I'm guessing your saying it's at 5.8 aprox and 1.6 aprox??

Comment: Yeah I guess.That should work. Oh, and also verify the solutions! You might turn out rejecting any of them!

Comment: Where did you get 9/4 from??

Comment: Simply from taking out the $\frac{3}{2}^2$ from the expression.

Comment: @S vengat what if the radius was 1??